# Antminer U1 running on raspberry pi not accepting shares

Tags: cgminer, mining-pool-shares, raspberry-pi, antminer

I'm new to bitcoin mining and am trying to figure everything out still. My Antminer U1 running on my raspberry pi using cgminer is not accepting any shares, and doesn't appear inside of the mining pool's (bitminter) dashboard. Also my antminer which was advertised at 1.6 GH has only ever gotten up to 600 MH. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The line `connected to mint.bitminter.com diff 512` means that the remote pool will only accept shares with an effective difficulty of 512 or above. Your miner has not yet found any shares with satisfy this rule, as noted by the line `best share 57`. It may take a number of hours at this speed to find a significantly difficult share that the pool will accept, when you do the log will print a line saying `accepted` or `rejected` depending on the pools response.

[image]

`diff 947/128` in this case means the remote pool was asking for minimum difficulty 128, and the miner managed to find a difficulty 947 share which satisfied this requirement.